# How to hide or remove placeholder using jquery placeholder.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery `placeholder.js`.  Is there a possibility of hiding or removing the placeholders.

I ave seen that using `watermark.js`, there is the option on `$watermark.HideAll()`; Is there something like that in `placeholder.js` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery placeholder function does not have any function that clears all placeholders with one function call. There is the `hidePlaceholder` function, so you could use the same selectors and call that.

Example:

```
$( 'input.formClass' ).hidePlaceholder();
```

And there should be no problems.  Just to confirm, [this](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-placeholder-js/) is the plugin I use.